# Expanding window map for time series

Tags: time-series

Given a `TimeSeries` object `ts`, how do I implement `ExpandingMap` similar to `MovingMap`, where the window is not moving but expanding. In pseudocode,

```
tsNew[tf] = f[TimeSeriesWindow[ts,{t0,tf}]],
```

where `t0=Min[ts["FirstTimes"]]`.

For example, the function `Accumulate` does exactly this with `f=Total`. I would like to have this functionality for an arbitrary function f.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain this behavior from `MovingMap` by using the `padding` parameter.

Here's some random data:

```
data = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[.3, .5], {0, 1, 0.01}, 2];
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image]

As an example I compute the rolling Max. The final 2 arguments set the window size to be the length of the whole time series, and instruct the function to use no padding, i.e. to compute the function over incomplete intervals. By default it is right-aligned.

```
MovingMap[Max, data, data["PathLength"], None]
ListLinePlot[%]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be easier/cleaner than

```
ClearAll[tsNew]
tsNew[s_, tf_, foo_] := Module[{tsw = TimeSeriesWindow[s, {s["FirstTime"], tf}], 
 bar, tsX, rules}, 
 tsX = TimeSeries[Array[x, {Length@tsw["Values"]}], Automatic]; 
 rules = Dispatch[Thread[tsX["Values"] -> tsw["Values"]]]; 
 Accumulate[TimeSeriesMap[bar, tsX]] /. Plus -> foo /. 
   foo[x__] :> foo[## & @@ ({x} /. bar -> Identity)] /. bar -> foo /. rules]
```

Example:

```
v = {2, 1, 6, 5, 7, 4};
t = {1, 2, 5, 10, 12, 15};
ts = TimeSeries[v, {t}];

ts["Path"]
```

> {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {5, 6}, {10, 5}, {12, 7}, {15, 4}}

```
tsNew[ts, 10, f]["Path"]
```

> {{0, f[2]}, {1, f[2, 1]}, {2, f[2, 1, 6]}, {3, f[2, 1, 6, 5]}}

```
tsNew[ts, 20, f]["Path"]
```

> {{0, f[2]}, {1, f[2, 1]}, {2, f[2, 1, 6]}, {3, f[2, 1, 6, 5]},
>      {4, f[2, 1, 6, 5, 7]}, {5, f[2, 1, 6, 5, 7, 4]}}

Comment: ... doesn't work for vector-valued time series.